# When setting fields via workflow into LIST A from lookup LIST B works only if the field has a value.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

When setting fields via workflow into **LIST A** from a "**lookup column based**" **LIST B** , will only work if a "**lookup field"** has a value. Otherwise the workflow cancels out if it reaches a lookup field that is empty.
As long as the lookup field has a value everything works, otherwise it just stops at the first lookup field that is empty, especially but not exclusive to date or choice fields.

**What I did to make it work thus far is:**

On the workflow:
 - I created a variable for each lookup field from LIST A.
and gave them a "string" value.
 - I then set each current item field value - correlating each to the "variables" created above ( letting me change the return field value to "Lookup Value ( as text ). Which I found to be a key element.

To avoid the issue with blank values I placed an If statement ( per field )  that if the **lookup field** was NOT empty, then set that current item field to the correlating variable associated to that **lookup field**.
-- It didn't work.

So I thought maybe the "blank dates" were defaulting to the default "invisible" 1/1/0001 so I used that value in the If statement to catch it but to no avail. Besides the issue still happened for text field lookup fields too that were also "blank".

**What am I doing wrong?**

As I mentioned , as long as the lookup fields have a value, all works, but when a field is empty it doesn't.
Also I thought that perhaps using an if statement to check and see if the field was blank before setting a field value might be a solution, but that too didn't either.

I would so greatly appreciate any of your generosity to find the solution. It's been a long day.

Comment: In your if condition , you have mentioned that if not empty certain actions being taken, but whether you have given any else statement and action block? if not why don't you try that and if that is blank assign the action that you want and see if that works